# how do i limit this line to 2 decimal places Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

On bundled options i.e.
radio
checkbox
select

i have a line of code

```
echo "<span class='bundleinstockprice'> +$".$_selection->getFinalPrice(). " </span>" ;
```

and this shows correctly on checkbox and select files
but for radio it display .0000 after price

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currency function of the core helper:

```php
echo "<span class='bundleinstockprice'> +" . Mage::helper('core')->currency($_selection->getFinalPrice(), true, false)
. "</span>" ;
```